# No response after clicking element (Python Selenium )

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on 3 webpages (Let say Page A to C) with Python Selenium.

Both Page A and B contain this button:

```
<button id="continue-button" type="button" class="form-button" data-autom="button-label"><span>Click</span></button>
```

When clicking this button on Page A, it will jump to Page B; When clicking it on Page B, it will jump to Page C

I use the following code to perform auto click action on Page A, it works great.

```
element_confirm = driver.find_element("id", 'continue-button')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element_confirm)
```

However, when I execute above code (different element name) again on Page B, nothing is happened.
No error message is on the log. I tried to print some text after driver.execute_script. It shows normally. I tried to find the element with "xpath", '//*[@data-autom="button-label"]', also no clcik action is performed. Checked the element is True (It means it can be found).

100% confirm that Page A to C are working fine when I click the button manually (using my mouse). Any recommendation?

Thank you!

Update:
As requested, this is the code that I use for Page B:

```
element_submit_two = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'continue-button')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element_submit_two)
```

Comment: You declared the element's (button) property for page A, did you declare that element's property for page B also? Post your complete code and URL.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you using outdated selenium? According to [docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/), you should use like that:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "continue-button")
button.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it can't explain why my code works fine on Page A. (By the way, I just tried By.ID and still same result)